# libprotobuf check failed while executing program on mac os

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers, build-process, protobuf-c

I have a project that uses protocol buffers and it works fine on linux and windows but on mac os I am getting following error while running the program. I confirmed I am using the correct libraries. I used `brew install protobuf` to install protocol buffers.

Generated the files using proper protoc and compiled and compilation succeed without any issues.

Version of library is **libprotoc 3.11.3**

> *[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc:812] CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning): 
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning):*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to add `-lpthread` when you compile with g++.